# Open div menu on click and close on mouseleave and click

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Hi have incorporated a div into the menu. in order to support touch devices im using Jquery to open and close instead of using css. works with normal menus, but cant seem to get it to function when dropping a div.

I understand that the div is a child of the li and have targeted it but it closes but by default i believe, as it snaps shut rather the glides up nicely. the menu then also opens and closes on hover after that.

still trying to get it to close on click but code is no good either.

html------

```
<ul id="mainmenu" style="width:300px; float:right;">
    <!--1st-->
    <li class="mainmenudrop"><a href="" class="dropsmall">Contact Us</a>

        <div class="dropout_1dropbox">
            <div class="dropbox_1">
                 <h2>Request Call Back</h2>

                <p style="font-size:11px; margin-left:1px;">Please enter your telephone number and we will contact you shortly.</p>
                <form action='feedback' accept-charset='utf-8' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='send_email' value='yes' />
                    <p>Tel:
                        <input class="norminput" name="Telephone" type="text" maxlength="25" style="font-size:13px; height: 14px; width:164px; margin-left:1px;" />
                        <input class="btn grey bbig" name="" value="Go" type="submit" style="width:50px; margin-left:10px; font-size:13px; height: 23px; line-height:13px;" />
                    </p>
                </form>
                 <h2>Email Us</h2>

                <form action='feedback' accept-charset='utf-8' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='send_email' value='yes' />
                    <p style="font-size:11px;  margin-left:1px;">If you have any questions please email us:</p>
                    <p>Email:
                        <input class="norminput" name="Name" type="text" size="20" style="font-size:13px; height:14px; width:145px; margin-left:1px;" />
                        <input class="btn grey bbig" name="" value="Send" type="submit" style="width:50px; margin-left:10px; height: 23px; line-height:13px; font-size:13px;" />
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <textarea id="textareae" style="width:247px; margin:2px 0px 0px 1px;" name="Questions" cols="1" rows="3"></textarea>
                    </p>
                </form>
            </div>
    </li>
    <!--2nd-->
    <li class="mainmenudrop"><a href="" class="dropsmall">My Account</a>

    </li>
    <!--3rd-->
    <li class="mainmenudrop"><a href="" class="dropsmall">Login</a>

        <div class="dropout_1dropbox">
            <div class="dropbox_1">
                    <h1>uiuhu</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

css-----

```
#mainmenu {
    list-style:none;
}
#mainmenu li {
    float:right;
    display: block;
    height:27px;
    line-height:27px;
    position:relative;
    border:none;
    z-index:999;
    cursor: default;
}
#mainmenu li:hover {
    background: #444489;
}
#mainmenu li a {
    font-family: Verdana, Arial;
    font-size:11px;
    color: #DFDFF0;
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#mainmenu li:hover a {
    color: #fff;
}
#mainmenu li .dropsmall {
    padding: 0 7px 0px 4px;
}
#mainmenu li:hover .dropsmall {
}
.dropout_1dropbox {
    margin:2px auto;
    float:left;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    /* Hides the drop down */
    text-align: left;
    padding:7px 7px 7px 7px;
    border:1px solid #aaa;
    border-top:none;
    border-radius: 0px 3px 3px 3px;
    background: #444489;
    display: none;
}
.dropout_1dropbox {
    width: 270px;
}
#mainmenu li:hover .dropout_1dropbox {
    left:auto;
    right:-1px;
    top:23px;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
}
.dropbox_1 {
    display:inline;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align:left;
    width:260px;
}
#mainmenu p, #mainmenu h2, #mainmenu h3, #mainmenu ul li {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    line-height:21px;
    font-size:12px;
    text-align: left;
    color: #eee;
}
#mainmenu h2 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight:400;
    margin:7px 0 14px 0;
    padding-bottom:4px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ff4200;
    text-align: left;
}
#mainmenu p {
    line-height:16px;
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
}
#mainmenu li:hover div a {
    font-size:11px;
    color:#4FA4F9;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#mainmenu li:hover div a:hover {
    color:#888;
}
#mainmenu li ul {
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0 0 12px 0;
}
#mainmenu li ul li {
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:24px;
    position:relative;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFF;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    float:none;
    text-align:left;
    width:130px;
}
#mainmenu li ul li:hover {
    background:none;
    border:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.arrowb {
    float:left;
    height: 12px;
    width: 13px;
    margin: 5px 3px 0 0;
    background: url("../images/arrowbloa.png") no-repeat 0px 5px;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.menubarright li:hover #rotateb {
    background: url("../images/arrowblo.png") no-repeat 0px 5px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
​
```

JQuery ---

```
$('a.dropsmall').click(function (e) {
    $(this).next("div").slideDown(200, 'easeOutCirc');
    console.log('div clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
});

$('li.mainmenudrop').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).parent("div").slideUp(300, 'easeInOutQuad');
});



$.extend($.easing,
 {
     easeInOutQuad: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        if ((t/=d/2) < 1) return c/2*t*t + b;
        return -c/2 * ((--t)*(t-2) - 1) + b;
    },
    easeOutCirc: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        return c * Math.sqrt(1 - (t=t/d-1)*t) + b;
    },
    easeInOutElastic: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
        var s=1.70158;var p=0;var a=c;
        if (t==0) return b;  if ((t/=d/2)==2) return b+c;  if (!p) p=d*(.3*1.5);
        if (a < Math.abs(c)) { a=c; var s=p/4; }
        else var s = p/(2*Math.PI) * Math.asin (c/a);
        if (t < 1) return -.5*(a*Math.pow(2,10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )) + b;
        return a*Math.pow(2,-10*(t-=1)) * Math.sin( (t*d-s)*(2*Math.PI)/p )*.5 + c + b;
    }

    });
```

close on click

fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/LkLazo02/4/

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: in developer view in firefox? or error in terms of how i want it to function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are causing the issue:

```
.dropout_1dropbox {
    left:-999em; /* Hides the drop down */
    display: none;
}

#mainmenu li:hover .dropout_1dropbox{
    left:auto;
    right:-1px;
}

$('li.mainmenudrop').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).parent("div").slideUp(300,'easeInOutQuad');
});
```

The `left:-999em` is the reason that the dropdown disappears once you hover out because it's no longer in the hover state so `left:auto` and `right:-1px` no longer apply.

There really isn't a reason to have the dropdown be offscreen as well as not displayed. You can have the dropdown in the correct position the entire time and just not displayed.

```
.dropout_1dropbox {
    left:auto;
    right:-1px;
    display: none;
}
```

Your `slideUp` selector is incorrect. It should be:

```
$('li.mainmenudrop').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).children("div").slideUp(300,'easeInOutQuad');
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/LkLazo02/6/

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The only easing functions provided by jQuery without the use of plugins are `swing` and `linear`. You're trying to use `easeOutCirc` which is only available from jQuery UI.

As shown in [slideDown](http://api.jquery.com/slidedown/#easing):

> As of jQuery 1.4.3, an optional string naming an easing function may
>   be used. Easing functions specify the speed at which the animation
>   progresses at different points within the animation. **The only easing
>   implementations in the jQuery library are the default, called swing,
>   and one that progresses at a constant pace, called linear**. More easing
>   functions are available with the use of plug-ins, most notably the
>   jQuery UI suite.

If you check the console you would get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function
```